# Is init always supposed to use the same memory block?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

```
    SomeClass *obj = [SomeClass alloc];
    NSLog(@"%@", obj);
    obj = [obj initWithNSNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
    NSLog(@"%@", obj);
```

Both log statements always display the same address. This is actually what I expected, but is this a standard Objective-C behavior? I mean can I count that this would be the same in different compiler/language versions?

What I would really like is a good tutorial how object initialization and related processes really work in Objective-C.

EDIT:
After Wain's answer adding information to the questions:
can I count that this would be the same in different compiler/language versions **if the initializer is implemented something like this**:

```
self = [super init];
if (self) {
//..
}
return self
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't guarantee it at any time really. Any `init` method implementation is within its rights to throw away the memory you have allocated and replace it with something else which is more appropriate (based on the parameters passed to it). If you try with `NSArray` you could well get different addresses back (anything which is implemented as a class cluster is a perfect candidate for this).

---

From your edit, `super` can do exactly the same thing. That is why you write:

```
self = [super init];
```

So if `super` does change the allocated memory then the `self` reference will be updated to point to the new allocation.

No, you can't guarantee that it will be the same across different versions of the SDK.

Comment: What if the initializer is implemented in a specific way, like I showed in the edited part of my questions?

Comment: What if the superclass is NSObject?

Comment: @Alex Not sure what you want to hear, your edit doesn't add any new information. This has nothing to do with compilers or language. `init` is not different from any other method and it's documentation says you should use the value it returns. How it is actually implemented can differ from class to class.